# How to Migrate Azure ASE v1 to v2?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I wonder if there is any docs or path of How to Migrate web apps from App Service Enviroment v1 to v2 on Azure?

Thank you so much.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can [move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan) an app to another App Service plan, as long as the source plan and the target plan are in the *same resource group and geographical region*.  Most likely your ASEv1 and ASEv2 will be in different resource groups so you will need to [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning) them.